# Bootstrap dropdown not working inside Horizontal description

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a dropdown menu inside an [horizontal description](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description) but the dropdown menu just doesn't toggle.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vertical-align">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Le panneau latéral <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">test2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </dt>
      <dd>Le panneau latéral est composé de différentes sections dynamiques qui se mettent à jour automatiquement en fonction des objets sélectionnés dans la carte. Ces sections sont: l'outil de recherche qui permet de déplacer la carte sur un objet géographique en particulier, la zone graphique, le gestionnaire de couches, l'outil information, le constat, et la légende de la carte.</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8681/)

Why isn't the dropdown menu opening? Is there a way to make it works ?

Comment: Works for me too. Chrome and Safari on OSX.

Comment: Just working on xs view

Comment: It's working in chrome, on windows, are you sure you don't have another error in your javascript. Open the developer tools and look undet the 'Console' tab

Comment: It's seems to works because jsfiddle is in small views... Just try with higher view, it doesn't work

Comment: @YenneInfo it works only if i minimize the view in order to make the button repositionning on top of the text

Comment: position relative when on xs : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8690/

Comment: It's because of div..list is behind the div so it is not visible..

Comment: @ Yenne Info i didn't see your answer so i posted...anyways   Below the Radar got solution fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just have to set the dropdown to relative position*

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8690/

**Code** :

```
.dropdown-menu{position:relative}
```